# TikZ: How to change the width of background layer?

Tags: tikz-pgf

As shown on the picture below, the TikZ `backgruound` library allows to create the background with automatical width/height settings.

[image]

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=magenta}]
\shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (10ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What if we want to define width or assign \textwidth, \columnwidth etc. as width of the background layer? The sketch of the desired result represented on the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may define a new key named `auto centering`. This key adds an empty node fitted around the content of your `tikzpicture`. The `minimum width` of this node is the length given as argument (default value is `\columnwidth`):

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  auto centering/.style={execute at end picture={
      \node[fit=(current bounding box),minimum width=#1-2*\tikz@framexsep,inner sep=0,
      ]{};
    }},
  auto centering/.default=\columnwidth,
}
\makeatother
```

In your document, add this key as *first* option of your `tikzpicture`s.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  auto centering/.style={execute at end picture={
      \node[fit=(current bounding box),minimum width=#1-2*\tikz@framexsep,inner sep=0,
      ]{};
    }},
  auto centering/.default=\columnwidth,
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
[auto centering,show background rectangle,background rectangle/.style={fill=magenta}]
\shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (10ex);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[4]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
[auto centering,show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=orange}]
\shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (10ex);
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
[auto centering,show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=lime}]
\shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (10ex);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[4]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

First draw the sphere in the middle:

```
\shade[ball color=blue] (0.5\linewidth,0) circle (10ex);   %% note 0.5\linewidth
```

To increase the width of the background to `\textwidth`, as you are painting the `background rectangle`, it is enough to draw some thing that runs across the text width like

```
\path(0,0) --(\linewidth,0);
```

This is an invisible line that runs across the `\linewidth`. Add `inner frame xsep=0pt` additionally to background rectangle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,showframe}   %% showframe just for demo
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
[show background rectangle,inner frame xsep=0pt, background rectangle/.style={fill=magenta,line width=0pt}]     
%% you can also use `tight background` instead of `inner frame xsep`.
\shade[ball color=blue] (0.5\linewidth,0) circle (10ex);
\path(0,0) --(\linewidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a simpler version in which the background is drawn first as a rectangle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\path[use as bounding box,line width=0pt,fill=magenta](-0.5\linewidth,-11ex) rectangle(0.5\linewidth,11ex);
\shade[ball color=blue] (0,0) circle (10ex);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```